# Ida Pro can't decompile big function

Tags: ida, decompilation

I tried to decompile (Pseudocode) a big function into binary with Ida Pro 7.7 but I got error :

```
The graph is too big (more than 1000 nodes) to be displayed on the screen.
Switching to text mode.
(you can change this limit in the graph options dialog)
```

What can I do to decompile that function?

Comment: It's decompiled, but it's to big to be seen on the screen. Your text view is the function decompiled

Comment: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305802/ida-pro-5-0-the-graph-is-too-big-more-than-1000-nodes-to-be-displayed-on-scre) post: `After some digging around it seems that in later versions of IDA it's possible to adjust the parameter under Options->General->Graph->Max nodes. However in the free version this options wasn't introduced. I hope this helps.`

Comment: That message comes up when you try to view the graph of a large function (with spacebar), not when you decompile it (TAB or F5). Which are you trying to do: view the graph of a function, or decompile it? (Pick one of the two; you can't do both at the same time, not in the same window pane at least.)